# Static block inside interface after decompile apk (java)

Tags: java, apk, decompiling

I decompile a some apk and as result get code below:

```
public interface IConfiguration {
   static {
       Covode.recordClassIndex(25378);
   }
... 
}
```

and like this :

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                static {
                    Covode.recordClassIndex(27414);
                }
...
}
```

as we can see this is java, but java doesnt support declare static block inside interface and anonimous classes. So, what is this? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an attempt to hinder tampering with an application's code.

Static initialisers appear in bytecode in order to initialise non-*compile time constant* static fields.